# Appending parent elements attribute to the URL of anchor tag href

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net, webforms, repeater

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rptStockListings">
  <ItemTemplate> 
    <li rank=<%#GetRank(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"r"))
       ...............
       <a href="<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Url")
```

I have URL already but i want to append the rank attribute of li element which is ancestor of this anchor with href="Url".

How can I do that?

Basically i want to pass information to the next opened page by anchor tag in the url itself.

Comment: It would be more helpful to provide accurate solution if you describe your problem with some examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this helps

```
<a onclick='openThis(<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Url"), this)'>Click here</a>
```

In javascript:

```
function openThis(url, obj) {
    var appendThis = $(this).closest("li").attr("rank");
    window.open(url+appendThis + , "_self")
}
```